# Does cut and paste work in terminal?

Tags: 12.04

Does cut & paste work in terminal? As in <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>?

Answer (score 2):

For pasting in the terminal you have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and for copying, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu and Linux in general you have several ways of copying and pasting.

For apps not related to a terminal environment you can simply do the following:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Copy
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - Paste 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> - Cut (Not available in Terminal by default)

On the terminal you simply add <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to this shortcuts, like this:

<kbd>RIGHT SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Copy
<kbd>RIGHT SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - Paste

The difference is that you need to use the Right keys.

Additional to this, if you have mouse support, this includes a quicker way to copy and paste information. by simply highlighting a text you are actually copying to a special clipboard that holds the last highlighted text you have selected. To paste this text, either on a non-terminal app or even inside the terminal you can simply click on the middle mouse button. This will paste the last text you have highlighted with your mouse.

Comment: The `RIGHT` isn't necessary, just Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V will work.

Comment: If you use other languages the default shortcuts change to the right only. In English it works on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Ctr + c is used to terminated a program (sending kill signal to current process). I think that there's a way to change that. Google is your friend to find how.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> for copy and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> for paste